# no se en que parte de mi código debo poner el ciclo para que cuando el usuario escriba una letra muestre el except y regrese a la sección de inputs?

Tags: python, bucles

```
try:
    h=int(input("hours"))
    t=int(input("cost"))
    def pagocomputado(h,t):
        if h> 48 :
            h= h - 48
            p = h *1.5*t + 48 *t
        else:
            p = h * t
        return p
        r= pagocomputado(h, t)
        print("pay: ",r)
except:
   print("write correct option " )
```

no se donde debo poner el cilo while exactamente para que cuando el usuario digite una letra el programa regrese a la seccion de inputs

Answer (score 0):

Ordenemos la cosa un poco: primero, las funciones se definen fuera de cualquier otro bloque de instrucciones. Si defines una función dentro de un `if`, la función sólo existira dentro del `if`, como muestra este ejemplo:

```
a = 2                     
if a == 1:                
    def funcion(x):       
        return x**x       
    print(funcion(a))     
else:                     
    print(funcion(a))
```

produce:

```
NameError: name 'funcion' is not defined
```

Volviendo al código de la pregunta, corresponde sacar fuera la función `pagocomputado`

```
def pagocomputado(h, t):
    if h > 48:
        h = h - 48
        p = h * 1.5 * t + 48 * t
    else:
        p = h * t
    return p
```

Ahora, para iterar pidiendo valores y calculando pagos, uso un ciclo infinito `while True:`, del cual escapare con `break` cuando los valores hayan sido correctamente ingresados y calculados

```
while True:
    try:
        h=int(input("hours"))
        t=int(input("cost"))
        r= pagocomputado(h, t)
        print("pay: ",r)
        break
    except:
       print("write correct option " )
```

dentro del ciclo pongo el `try`. Si lo pongo fuera del ciclo, cuando se produzca una excepción se terminar el `while`, pero lo que quiero es que siga trabajando.

**Demo**

```
def pagocomputado(h, t):
    if h > 48:
        h = h - 48
        p = h * 1.5 * t + 48 * t
    else:
        p = h * t
    return p

while True:
    try:
        h=int(input("hours"))
        t=int(input("cost"))
        r= pagocomputado(h, t)
        print("pay: ",r)
        break
    except:
       print("write correct option " )
```

produce

```
hours10
cost3
pay:  30

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: muchas gracias, ahora tengo mas claridad en el tema de la aplicación de loops con funciones